# execution time for multiprocesses program (linux)

Tags: c, linux

I have the following c code

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
child_pid [i]= fork ();
if (child_pid[i] != 0) {
       printf ("");
       printf ("");
}
else
      printf ("");
```

I want to calculate execution time for this program
I tried the following command 
time ./a.out 5 
the result was

```
real    0m1.009s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
root@bt:~/Desktop#
```

what should I do to get a correct formatted output?
can I show only the execution time without showing execution result?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your parent processes should `wait` for all child processes to terminate. Otherwise `time` would measure (and wait) only the first process. That's what you observe: the first process terminates, `time` prints its working times, and then child processes continue their work.

One way to do it would be to add something like

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) if (child_pid[i]) wait(NULL);
```

just before `exit(0);`.

As far as I know, there are no means to make `time` to wait until all child processes terminate.